# What is the connection string for Google Cloud mySQL, in node.js?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, connection-string

The scenario is as follows:
I am writing an node.js app locally and want it (the mySQL modul, rather) to connect to a mySQL db running on Google Cloud Platform.

I can not get the connection string right and keep getting errors. GCP holds two names for the database - one i picked, one generated, more complex. Problably I should supply one of these into the connection string as "database", the host is likely the IP address with port (or not(?)), I am not sure what the "user" should be, or if it is necessary. Not enough info on the GCP help pages or elsewhere.

**tl;dr:** I need the following to connect a node.js app with a mySQL module remotely to a GCP database:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"11.222.333.444:3306",
  user: "me"
  password:"passwo3d",
  database:"projectname-1528892969949:europe-west5:dbname"
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw connection string should look something like: `mysql://user:password@localhost:port/db`

So I think your code should look something like:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"11.222.333.444", <-- remove the port from your string
  user: "me"
  password:"passwo3d",
  database:"dbname" <--  you have it as the instance name .. its just suppose to be the DB name
});
```

You can also try connecting to the instance using the [cloud proxy setup](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy). You host would just be localhost.

Finally you can always go the GCP console -> go to your instance and open up a shell. I think they print out the `gcloud` cmd in there and you can copy values from the console as well.

Depending on how you are pushing your code, you may have to change a few connections strings in your manifests as well. If you can share those  I can help further.

Comment: Thanks Prashant. I didn't realize that the instance wasn't an instance of the actual database, rather an SQL serve-like service instance, which contains databases.

Answer (score -1):

For that to happen, you have to first enable remote access for your mysql on your GCP. A step by step guide is over [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access), you can leave the first few steps for installing mysql.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think this resolves my issue. I am not running a Virtual Machine, which the help page you suggested reffers to, and I have, anyway, allowed remote connections to the mySQL instance directly. What I need is the correct conn string, or maybe something else I am not aware of.