# Trying to connect simple Java program to Google Cloud Platform MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform, jdbc

I am trying to connect this small Java program to my MySQL Database instance
on GCP for educational purposes.

This code works well with the instance I have locally on localhost and port 3306.
However, this is not very practical or useful.

**Scenarios that work:**

1. Connecting Java client program to MySQL database served locally.
2. Connecting MySQL Workbench client to MySQL database served locally.
3. Connecting MySQL Workbench client to MySQL database served on Google Cloud Platform.

**My objective:**

1. Connect very simple Java client program to MySQL database served on Google Cloud Platform.

**Jar files used:**

1. mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar
2. mysql-socket-factory-1.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

**IDE used:**

1. Eclipse

**The code:**

---

```
    package test;

import java.sql.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String CREDENTIALS = "jdbc:mysql://google/emexdb?cloudSqlInstance=ethereal-shine-354205:us-central1:emexdb-mysql&socketFactory=google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=****&password=***********";
        try
        {
            //Get a connection to database
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(CREDENTIALS);
            
            //Create a statement
            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            //Execute SQL query
            ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from Test;");
            //Process the result set
            while(myRs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(myRs.getNString("id")+"  "+myRs.getString("_name"));
            }
            
            myConn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception eSQL)
        {
            eSQL.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the error message Eclipse is giving me:**

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot connect to MySQL server on google:3,306.

Make sure that there is a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to and that the machine this software is running on is able to connect to this host/port (i.e. not firewalled). Also make sure that the server has not been started with the --skip-networking flag.


at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:462)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:253)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.getSocketConnection()" because the return value of "com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.getProtocol()" is null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:972)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    ... 5 more
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
**Thank you!**

Comment: What is the 'bind-address' in your mysql config file?

Comment: @SachinVairagi How do I find this config file?

Comment: May I know which OS you have on GCP?

Comment: @SachinVairagi Debian Linux I think

Comment: you can check "/etc/my.cnf" or "/etc/mysql/my.cnf", reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location

Comment: @goldie4, Were you able to connect to the Database using the suggestion and references shared by Sachin and maxiangelo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you whitelisted your public IP in the settings of your GCP MySQL database?

**You can do that here:**
Your GCP Project ⇾
SQL (Press the three horizontal bars in the left corner) ⇾
Connections ⇾
Authorised networks ⇾ ADD NETWORK

You can use [this](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) Website to get your public IP.

Comment: I have the public IP address of my computer listed in the Authorized Networks list. I am not sure if this is the same as "whitelisting".

Comment: I think your connection string is wrong, try the actual IP of the cloudsql database. Akin to something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755760/what-is-the-connection-string-for-google-cloud-mysql-in-node-js